# Loading components webpack encore symfony error 404

Tags: php, symfony, assets, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

i have problem with loading assets via webpack encore everything is default after installation, i followed this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html. I'm getting 404, maybe it's something with server configuration?

Here's code for wepback.config.js that setting path:

```
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
.setPublicPath('/build')
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
```

and my call from base.html.twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
 {% endblock %}
```

If anyone can point me my mistake i would be greateful

I already tried change permissions to files, reinstall webpack encore, restart server, try to fix by changing path's to files

tree view lookslike that:

```
project

- assets

-- css

--- app.css

-- js

--- app.js

- public

-- build

--- app.css

--- app.js

--- entrypoints.json

--- manifest.json

--- runtime.js

- webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Have you tried `yarn encore dev` in project root folder?

Comment: @AndreaManzi yes i tried, 
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1154ms                                                                                                                                                  

 I  3 files written to public/build

Entrypoint app = runtime.js app.css app.js
Done in 4.74s.

Comment: 404 only for assets?

Comment: Please post an example url that you are trying to reached and an example of url that return 404

Comment: Your symfony configuration seems to be correct

Comment: @AndreaManzi, good point it's seems i can't load any css & js. the only thing that works is include('part.html.twig') in my templates folder. I tried load css with {% block stylesheets %} and simple <link> from many places it's not working. 
[http://cmslookslike.pl/build/test_load_by_link.css](http://cmslookslike.pl/build/test_load_by_link.css) - this i tried call by <link>

[http://cmslookslike.pl/build/app.js](http://cmslookslike.pl/build/app.js) - example of loading by assets

Comment: Maybe a htaccess or virtualhost config problem? Please post your public/.htaccess file